# DecimalFormat WITHOUT scientific notation

Tags: java, floating-point, notation, decimalformat

I have a DecimalFormat like this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.###");
```

Then I have 3 methods which just return a float value for time, potential and current, with many decimals in case of the two last ones. So I'm trying to get an output message with the 3 values formated, so:

```
System.out.println("t="+df.format(getTime())+"(s), v="+df.format(getPotential())+"(V), i="+df.format(getI())+"(A)");
```

Time just count seconds from 0 to 10, without any decimal, and looks ok until it gets to 10. Then it shows 1E+1. I just don't understand why, since I have read at the API and it shouldn't be in scientific notation if I don't use an 'E' character at the DecimalFormat.

Also, potential goes from 0 to a certain value, using 3 decimals. Looks OK, but from 0 to 0.01, it appears with 4 decimals, being the last one always 0.

Any explanation to this behaviour of DecimalFormat? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE. http://sscce.org/

Comment: please provide output of your function without applying decimal format

Comment: That would be (changing very quickly):
0(s), 0.000010254 (v), 0.0000400137 (A)
0(s), 0.000010379 (V), 0.0000380921 (A)
... etc. Maybe with even more decimals. It's hard to provide an exact output, and I think it's of no interest at all for the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be simpler to use printf in your case :

```
System.out.printf("t=%d(s) v=%.2f(V) i=%.2f(A)\n", getTime(), getPotential(), getI());
```

Comment: That approach gave me problems, that's why I tried new ways of formatting. Indeed, this worked, but gave problems with a diferent part of the program non-directly related, so I prefer a different way.